# pandas read_csv() change the index values

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHBKz.png)

1. List item

This is a question of how to use pandas read_csv()  I want to ask all of you a favor that how to change the index values please

Comment: How would you like to change them? What's the result you want?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first take the  [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How to ask a good question. Please [do not post images of code or error messages](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - post as text here